# How to get operand of instruction using qemu

Tags: qemu, instructions, operand

I would like to get the operand of an i386 instruction that is executed in my QEMU guest. for example ,I'd like to get the operand`0x400400` of `40053a:e8 c1 fe ff ff        callq  400400 <puts@plt>` ,But it seems that I can not find the `C function` used to get the operand.

Comment: Are you running QEMU in KVM(hardware accelerated virtualization) or TCG (pure emulation) mode ?

Comment: @ArnabjyotiKalita Yes，I am running QEMU in TCG mode